# Fastest way to copy List(Of T) Class in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, linq, class

VB.NET 2012
I create a partial list of foo that will remain static after its built, then a second list of Foo that will always have everything from the partial list.  My question is...  What is a fast or fastest way to copy one list to the other? Is there a faster way, without looping? 
See method `Combine` in `Class1`

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
    Private _initFoo As New Class1()
    Private _postFoo As New Class1()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        _initFoo.Init()
        _postFoo.Combine(_initFoo, _postFoo) ' **
    End Sub
End Class


Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Public Class Class1
    Private FooLst As New List(Of Foo)

    Public Class Foo
        Public Property Item1 As String
        Public Property Item2 As String
    End Class

    Public Sub Init()
        FooLst.Add(New Class1.Foo With {.Item1 = "1", .Item2 = "A"})
        FooLst.Add(New Class1.Foo With {.Item1 = "2", .Item2 = "B"})
    End Sub

    Public Sub Combine(readFrom As Class1, writeTo As Class1) ' **
        ' Is there a faster or way to copy one list to the other?
        ' possibly without looping though each item in the readFrom list?
        For Each f As Foo In readFrom.FooLst
            writeTo.FooLst.Add(New Foo With {.Item1 = f.Item1, .Item2 = f.Item2})
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you actually need to clone the items as you go? Note that even if you use code that doesn't have a loop in *your* source, *something* is going to be looping somewhere.

Comment: you are cloning - making new Foos - not copying the existing ones to the new list.  Is that what you intend?

Comment: I don't see a way around looping in you want separate instances within each list.  If you don't, then the fastest way is probably to use the `List<T>` constructor.

Comment: I create a 'partial list' that I need to save.  The partial list has to be included in a 'complete list'.  The 'complete list' can be discarded and rebuilt depending on how the user interacts with controls.

Comment: If speed is really matters, use arrays and the [Array.Copy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx). But it won't make a noticeable difference unless yo have very long lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use AddRange to add the contents of one list to an existing list:

```
list1.AddRange(list2)
```

This adds the contents of list2 to list1, retaining the original items in list1.

Comment: It's all on one line, easier to read and seems as fast as the loop so  Thanks!